# the whole experience left a bad taste in my mouth?

Tags: meaning, idioms, terminology

How would you explain a meaning in the details?

Answer (score 2):

This expression indicates that the experience was unpleasant, sufficiently so that you would be unwilling to

1. repeat the experience, or have a different experience that appeared to be closely similar, or
2. trust the person/people who managed the experience, or encouraged you to have it.

Generally, there is also an implication that you were encouraged to have expectations that were not met, and not met in ways that suggest that the expectations were encouraged under false pretenses.